# How to create PDF/A file from Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2009

Tags: pdf-generation, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics

We need to build PDF/A file from some prints, Is there a way to build PDF/A file directly in Dynamics AX 2009?

Answer (score 1):

- I assume that you want to do it via X++.  Here is [a way to do it for a standard report](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/t/30007.aspx).
- For 'special' documents such as Sales Invoices or a customer Confirmation note here is [a useful Blog (post)](http://axwonders.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/save-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-report.html).
- Also check out the [Print Management facility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4393) (it's not for all reports), and provide more for your users :)

Answer (score 0):

see this link:
[https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-create-a-PDFA-ba742648][1]

1) add dll SautinSoft.Document.dll
2) see this code (Ax 2012)

```
SautinSoft.Document.PdfCompliance compliance;
SautinSoft.Document.DocumentCore document;    
SautinSoft.Document.PdfSaveOptions options = new SautinSoft.Document.PdfSaveOptions();    

options.set_Compliance(SautinSoft.Document.PdfCompliance::PDF_A);    
document = SautinSoft.Document.DocumentCore::Load("C:\\test.pdf");  
document.Save("C:\\test.pdf",options);
```